# How do I add a value to a specific row# and column#?

Tags: java, arrays, element

Let's say I have a 2-d array of doubles of 3 rows and 5 columns named sales

```
double [][] sales = new double [3][5];
```

How do I add a value to a specific cell by row and column number? I am trying to write a program that asks user for the row number, then reads it, the column number, then reads it, then the value to put into the row and column number, then adds that value to the specific row and column that the user specified.

Comment: It is useful to realize that `double[][]` is not a grid with coordinates; it is an **array of arrays**, a 'double array' array. So `new double[3][5]` is really saying, "I want an array containing 5 arrays of doubles that are 3 elements long".

Answer (score 0):

Reference the array at those specific locations, bearing in mind that arrays in Java are zero-based.

If you want to access data in the 1st row, 3rd column, you'd write:

```
sales[0][2] = 12.345;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following.

```
sales[row-1][column-1]=value;
```

Also check if row and column does not exceed their max and min values.